# sonar-runner unable to launch on fedora19

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, jenkins-cli

My jenkins job is failing with the below error.. i have verified the database process and its login as well...

It looks to be fine..

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
```

Result of nestat

```
# netstat -an |grep 5432 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5432 127.0.0.1:35438 ESTABLISHED tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5432 127.0.0.1:35092 ESTABLISHED tcp6 0 0 ::1:5432 :::* LISTEN tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:35092 127.0.0.1:5432 ESTABLISHED tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:35317 127.0.0.1:5432 ESTABLISHED tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:35438 127.0.0.1:5432 ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: # netstat -an |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:35438         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:35092         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35092         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35317         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35438         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED

Comment: Can you post the configuration of sonar runner (remove passwd of db) ?

Answer (score 0):

On observing ..i found that the configuration in the posgresql.conf file needs to be changes, the parameter listen_addresses... after changing it..it worked fine.

/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'